# Isolating $t$ in doubling time formula: $500000 = 120 \cdot 2^{\frac t 2}$

Tags: exponential-function

I am a having trouble figuring out a way to rearrange the formula $500000 = 120 \cdot 2^{\frac t 2}$ in order to isolate *t* and get the time.

Comment: what do you know about logarithms?

Comment: I guess I'd use something like $log$ to isolate the exponent since if I have $a^b=c$ then $log_ac=b$.

Comment: I know little about log. I can do some problems with log. The thing that's throwing me off here is that t isn't just t, but rather t/2.

Comment: If that's throwing you off, then let $x = t/2$, and solve for $x$. Once you've done that, then $t=2x$.

Comment: For future reference, its better if you include your attempts and or background with the relevant math to avoid having comments like these filling up your question space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let t/2=x
Divide both sides by 120 and take log to the base 2 on both sides to give you the value for x and then put the value of x in the formula for t

Comment: Thanks, I understood what to do!